# Jenkins, tomcat и плагин org.codehaus.mojo tomcat?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

Проект на spring+maven+remote tomcat + jenkins

В процессе использования maven - плагина codehaus.mojo  tomcat на CI столкнулся с такой проблемой:

Если сервер чистый, без установленных на него war-файлов, то tomcat:deploy - работает хорошо, но повторный его вызов вызывает ошибку(так как не удален предыдущий war-файл)

Если сервер чистый, то tomcat:redeploy вызовет ошибку(нечего перезаписывать)

Если использую связку tomcat:undeploy + tomcat:deploy - то получу ошибку, если на сервере ничего до этого не было.

Как мне выйти из этой ситуации? Можно ли при настройке Jenkins сделать шаг необязательным. То есть попытаться сделать undeploy и, вне зависимости, прошел он или провалился, выполнить следующие шаги(деплой и тесты)?

Answer (score 0):

проблема в криво написанном приложении, при deploy на сервер, происходит автоматический undeploy, если приложение уже установлено.. проблема возникает при остановке - не все ресурсы освобождаются и какие-то файлы приложения держатся, поэтому и не удаляются и приводят к ошибке..